# Factory-bean and PropertiesOverrideConfigurer

Tags: spring, factory

how can I use a PropertiesOverrideConfigurer with a Spring factory bean? These are my bean definitions.

```
<bean id="dataFeedFactory" class="com.gottex.gottware.datafeeds.factories.DataFeedFactory">
    <property name="dummyIntervalDistribution" ref="fixedIntervalGenerator"/>
    <property name="dummyStep" value="0.0001"/>
    <property name="serverAddress" value="${com.gottex.gottware.datafeeds.bloomberg.server.address}"/>
    <property name="serverPort" value="${com.gottex.gottware.datafeeds.bloomberg.server.port}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="referenceDataRequester" factory-bean="dataFeedFactory" factory-method="referenceDataRequester">
        <constructor-arg name="datasource" value="${com.gottex.gottware.datafeeds.mode}"/>
</bean>
```

I would like to replace the constructor-arg "datasource" with something coming from another properties file. I know how to use PropertiesOverrideConfigurer for a spring bean, what for a factory bean?

Answer (score 0):

The right strategy to replace the constructor-arg is to use a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer with lower order, so that the existing value for the property is replaced, like the following

```
<bean id="mainPropertiesConfigurer"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="properties">
        <props>
            <prop key="myProp">mypropvalue</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="order" value="100"/>
</bean>

<bean id="overriderPropertiesConfigurer"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="properties">
        <props>
            <prop key="myProp">mypropoverridenvalue</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="order" value="1"/>
</bean>
```